# How did Peter, James and John know that the two figures (Matthew 17:3) beside Christ at his transfiguration were Moses and Elijah?

Tags: moses, elijah, disciple

Having never seen Moses and Elijah how did the disciples recognised them? Also there were no evidence that Jesus introduced them to the disciples. If the recognition was ”in spirit” what would that mean?

> And, behold, there appeared unto them Moses and Elias talking with him. [Matthew 17:3 KJV]

Comment: Great Question! - Which Gospel account did you want us to analyze : Mark 9:1-4, Matthew 17:1-3 or Luke 9:28-32?

Comment: Also note [ 2 Peter 1:16-21 ] describes the same event : " we ourselves heard this declaration made from heaven when we were with Him ". - Perhaps the phrase "φωνὴν ἡμεῖς ἠκούσαμεν ἐξ οὐρανοῦ" means something declared in scripture. Perhaps the disciples saw Jesus studying the words of Malachi 4:4-6 in English Bibles | Malachi 3:22-24 in the Hebrew Tanakh, and finally 'heard' (understood) who Jesus was.

Comment: ‎@חִידָה Exactly right. They recognised Moses and Elijah ‘through’ the Tanakh. They ‘knew’ Moses and Elijah from the Tanakh. The Tanakh revealed who they were seeing - and it would’ve been quite ‘instant/natural’. (No surprise). Was going to answer, but you already have.

Comment: How did Ezekiel know that certain images were 'cherubim' ? How did John know that a certain image was Diabolos ? It is part of the gift of a vision to be (also) given the understanding along with the imagery. Those who have such dreams and visions know the sensation of understanding and interpretation being granted alongside the visionary images.

Comment: I have edited to focus on Matthew's account in order to bring the question into line with site requirements. Please feel free to edit to another gospel account, if that is desired.

Answer (score 5):

How did Ezekiel know that certain images were 'cherubim' ? How did John know that a certain image was Diabolos ?

It is part of the gift of a vision to be (also) given the understanding along with the imagery.

Those who have such dreams and visions know the sensation of understanding and interpretation being granted alongside the visionary images.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is - We are not told.  However, we have the following credible possibilities:

- The disciples are recorded as hearing :Jesus talking with Moses and Elijah", Matt 17:3, Mark 9:4, Luke 9:30.  Therefore, perhaps they heard Jesus say their names as they greeted each other.
- They were expecting something like this as per OT prophecies about both Moses and Elijah from passages such as Mal 4:4-6.
- They were informed and understood the identity of Moses and Elijah supernaturally as part of the transfiguration.

Any of these is possible but the first is the simplest.